# python pandas read_csv how to parse microsecond

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have csv file with microsecond as time.

```
Time,Bid

2014-03-03 23:30:30:224323224323,0.8925

2014-03-03 23:30:30:224390224390,0.892525

2014-03-03 23:30:30:224408224408,0.892525

2014-03-03 23:30:30:364299364299,0.892525
```

how do i parse microsecond into Time index with read_csv() or other function
read_json maybe?

Thank you!

Comment: Microseconds? Those numbers have 12 digits, which would make them picoseconds.

Comment: Are you sure your data is correct, it looks like your microseconds is repeated you could do this after importing using strptime: `df.Time = df.Time.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x[:-6], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f'))`

Comment: much faster than @EdChum soln would bet to read in with ``object`` specified, then use ``to_datetime`` and the specified format

Comment: thanks to all of you for such quick/right answer. It saves me lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from @Jeff's comment you can do the following:

```
In [29]:
import pandas as pd
# specifically set the Time column to object dtype
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\temp1.txt', dtype={'Time':object})
df

Out[29]:

                               Time       Bid
0  2014-03-03 23:30:30:224323224323  0.892500
1  2014-03-03 23:30:30:224390224390  0.892525
2  2014-03-03 23:30:30:224408224408  0.892525
3  2014-03-03 23:30:30:364299364299  0.892525

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [32]:
# trim the erroneous data
df.Time=df.Time.apply(lambda x: x[:-6])
# now apply to_datetime and pass the format string
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
df.dtypes

Out[32]:

Time    datetime64[ns]
Bid            float64
dtype: object
```